# Getting the function $F(x)$ knowing $f(1)$ and $F(x)=$definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

$f$ is a function with continious derivate in ℝ and also you know $f (1)=1$ $$F(x)= \int_{0}^{x}f=x\cdot e^{-x}+ax+b$$ 
The letter ask to get a,b,and f

$F(x)$ gives me $(x-1)\cdot e^x+a{x^2/2}+bx+1$ and when I replace with $f(1)=1$ it gives me $a/2+b+1=1$ so I cannot get an specific number for $a,b$ ,the excersice didn't clarify if has to get an specfic number, is correct or I missed something?.

UPDATE 1:
When reading the post, i realized that $f(1)=1$ not $F(1)=1$ so is bad all that I haave previously resolved. and the problems ask to get $f,a,b$ not $F$, so i didn't nderstand, $f$ isn't $x\cdot e^{-x}+a\cdot x+b$?

anyway,I replaced x with 1 in $f(1):1\cdot e^{-1}+a\cdot1+b=1$ 
so I get $e^{-1}+a+b=1$ so, I get witouth possible to get a and b again as exact numbers, and the problem ask for $f$ to, not for $F$ so or the problem is bad or is misunderstand.

Comment: You problem is: $F$ is a function with continious derivate in ℝ and also you know $f (1)=1$ $$F(x)= \int_{0}^{x}(f(x)=x\cdot e^{-x}+ax+b)dx$$ or $$F(x)= \int_{0}^{x}f(x)dx=x\cdot e^{-x}+ax+b$$?

Comment: the first one, F=(x) is the integal of f(x).

Comment: si hablo español, la primera que pusiste ($f(x)=x.e^-x+ax+b)dx$, solo te marca que f(x) es esa función,por lo menos interpreto así la letra.
English:
I reffer that is $(f(x)=x.e^-x+ax+b)dx $,

Comment: El ejercicio lo sacaste de algún libro o tienes el enlace para poder verlo, es que dices que es de la primera forma pero como lo editaste nuevamente parece de la segunda.

Comment: http://snag.gy/jgrF1.jpg ahi te saque un screenshot, en realidad en la propuesta nisiquiera esta el dx, por eso imagino yo que es de la forma uno,porque la interpeto que f(x)= a eso y la integral de eso es F(x) pero la verdad, puede que este errado.

Comment: Si, en verdad no se especifica muy bien pero creo que es de la segunda, forma es decir la integral da ese resultado. Editare la respuesta que estimo más conveniente para el problema, pues se debe derivar $F$ que es una de las condiciones que no usas en tus resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in this case, then the first theorem fundamental of calculus say that:

$$F(x)=\int_0^x{f(t)\,dt}\Longrightarrow F'(x)=f(x)$$
how $F'(x)=(1-x)e^{-x}+a=f(x)$ then how $f(1)=1\Longrightarrow F'(1)=(1-1)e^{-1}+a=f(1)=1 $ 
then $$a=1$$ therefore $f(x)=(1-x)e^{-x}+1$, $a=1$ and $b=0$
.

Comment: $b=0$,  see the process in the answer of @martycohen

Comment: yes,thanks for the effort,was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You integrated the expression
instead of differentiating.

From 
$F(x)= \int_{0}^{x}f=x.e^{-x}+ax+b$,
differentiating we get
$f(x) = e^{-x}-x e^{-x}+a
=(1-x)e^{-x}+a$.
Setting $x=1$,
$1=f(1)
= a
$.
Therefore $f(x) = (1-x)e^{-x}+1$.

Setting $x=0$ in the definition of $F$,
$F(0)
= \int_{0}^{0}f=0.e^{-0}+a*0+b
=b$.
But $F(0) = 0$,
since it the integral of $f$
on an interval of length $0$.
Therefore,
$b = 0$
and
$F(x)= \int_{0}^{x}f=x.e^{-x}+x
$.